# Replace Android default webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to implement my own webview and replace Android default webview with my implementation (i mean that all applications which uses webview widget will be rendered using my implementation). Is there a way to do that? I would like to hear your advice.

Answer (score 3):

In your own build of Android from AOSP Marshmallow and Lollipop, you can change the value of `config_webViewPackageName` variable in `frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml` ([source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-mr1-release/core/res/res/values/config.xml#L2108)) to point to your WebView implementation package.

Note that despite the fact that WebView comes in its own apk, it is still part of the framework, so it can't be replaced with some other implementation on existing devices. It's similar to asking "how can I replace the default `TextView`".