# Replacing default AOSP WebView with the WebView from the PlayStore

Tags: android, webview

We use a `custom Android ROM` which in-turn uses the `default WebView` with version `48`. We want to replace that APK with the APK from the Play Store with version `74`. Both have different package names.

I've read this [replacing default WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335643/replace-android-default-webview) and done changing my `frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml` values to point to the new APK's package name.

Now, when I try to launch the Activity which hosts the WebView I get this stacktrace

```
E/webviewchromiumloader: Failed to open relro file /data/misc/shared_relro/libwebviewchromium64.relro: No such file or directory
E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.google.android.webview-1@base.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
E/cr_LibraryLoader: Unable to load library: webviewchromium
E/WebViewFactory: error instantiating provider
Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
```

What am I missing here? or any alternative library which has the latest WebView

**Solved here** -  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663461/updating-webview-on-aosp-android-6-0)

Comment: "We want to replace that APK with the APK from the Play Store with version 74" -- did  you license this from Google?

Comment: @CommonsWare ah, no! Should we? I have no idea on this front

Comment: I'm not sure if it is what you want but [here is](https://www.chromium.org/developers/androidwebview/android-webview-beta) how to change the default webview. if you don't want the beta, you canjust use `chrome stable`

Comment: @Kilarn123 Yes, I have the APK with me, now I need my custom ROM Android to point to that APK for WebView

Comment: "Should we?" -- what evidence do you have that you are authorized to copy it? When  you discussed this with your attorney, what did the attorney suggest?

Comment: yes but the part in developer options where you can choose it ? isn't it what you want ?

Comment: @CommonsWare we haven't discussed this with any attorney, we figured out that the WebView from the PlayStore with version 74 was supporting our use-case rather than the default one version 48 which we already have

Comment: @Kilarn123 we run Android M, so selecting WebView implementations is not an option

Comment: Try reading this https://developers.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview.
It is only from Android Lollipop that webview has moved to separate APK. The WebView will auto-update for mobile devices with Android L and above. If you update webview from playstore you should see the effect on webview that you are creating, if anything is applicable